# Plot mean values for specific column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

as the code shows below, I am trying to plot the columns on the x-axis and only the mean value on the y axis ... How can I code that using matplotlib ?

print(df.agg({

```
'Total N, 1985 (Kg.)': ['min', 'mean', 'max', 'median', 'skew'],
'Total N, 2007 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
'Total N, 2007 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
'Total N, 2010 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
'Total N, 2011 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
'Total N, 2012 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
'Total N, 2013 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
'Total N, 2014 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
'Total N, 2015 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
'Total N, 2016 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
'Total N, 2017 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
'Total N target, 2025 (Kg.)': ['min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'skew'],
    
    }))
```

thank

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? To get help you get started you can get all the columns by doing `x = df.columns` and all of the mean values by `y = df.iloc[3, :]`. I am guessing based off of your post. If you require additional help try adjusting your post by reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Simulating your data

- `agg()` as per you question
- use `loc[]` to pick out just mean
- a bit of sugar to rotate labels

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,6])

df = pd.DataFrame({f"Total N, {y} (Kg.)":np.random.randint(20,100, 20) for y in range(2010,2017)})
df["Total N target, 2025 (Kg.)"] = df.mean(axis=1).astype(int)-5

df.agg({c:['min', 'mean', 'max', 'median', 'skew'] for c in df.columns}).loc["mean"].plot(ax=ax, kind="bar")
l = ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 90)
```

[image]